# Open JQuery DateTimePicker Calendar if button Pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, datetimepicker

When button is pressed, I want to show the datetimepicker object "input."

It is not working and I'm not sure why. Any advice would be appreciated.

I used the style guide from https://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/ and I'm not sure where my error arises from.

Thanks!

```
<button onclick="display()">
<script>

$('#input').datetimepicker();

function display(){
  console.log('HEY');
  $('#input').datetimepicker('show');
}

</script>
```

Comment: Have you included the script and css for the datetimepicker, before the script shown in the code sample?

Comment: @Geshode, yes <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="node_modules/jquery-datetimepicker/jquery.datetimepicker.css" >
<script src="node_modules/jquery-datetimepicker/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/jquery-datetimepicker/build/jquery.datetimepicker.full.min.js"></script>